# How to create differences between several pairs of columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyr

I have a panel (cross-sectional time series) dataset. For each group (defined by (NAICS2, occ_type) in time ym) I have many variables. For each variable I would like to **subtract each group's first (`dplyr::first`) value from every value of that group**.
Ultimately I am trying to take the Euclidean difference between the vector of each row 's group's first entry, (i.e. sqrt(c_1^2 + ... + c_k^2).

I was able to create the a column equal to the first entries for each group:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ym, NAICS2, occ_type) %>% 
  distinct(ym, NAICS2, occ_type, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  arrange(occ_type, NAICS2, ym) %>% 
  select(group_cols(), ends_with("_scf")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols(), ends_with("_scf")), 
            list(first = dplyr::first))
```

I then tried to include variations of `f.diff = . - dplyr::first(.)` in the list, but none of those worked. I googled the dot notation for a while as well as first and lag in dplyr timeseries but have not been able to resolve this yet.

Ideally, I unite all variables into a vector for each row first and then take the difference.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(ym, NAICS2, occ_type) %>% 
  distinct(ym, NAICS2, occ_type, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  arrange(occ_type, NAICS2, ym) %>% 
  select(group_cols(), ends_with("_scf")) %>% 
  unite(vector, c(-group_cols(), ends_with("_scf")), sep = ',') %>%
# TODO: DISTANCE_BETWEEN_ENTRY_AND_FIRST
  mutate(vector.diff = ???)
```

I expect the output to be a numeric column that contains a distance measure of how different each group's row vector is from its initial row vector.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
structure(list(ym = c("2007-01-01", "2007-02-01"), NAICS2 = c(0L, 
0L), occ_type = c("is_middle_manager", "is_middle_manager"), 
    Administration_scf = c(344, 250), Agriculture..Horticulture..and.the.Outdoors_scf = c(11, 
    17), Analysis_scf = c(50, 36), Architecture.and.Construction_scf = c(57, 
    51), Business_scf = c(872, 585), Customer.and.Client.Support_scf = c(302, 
    163), Design_scf = c(22, 17), Economics..Policy..and.Social.Studies_scf = c(7, 
    7), Education.and.Training_scf = c(77, 49), Energy.and.Utilities_scf = c(25, 
    28), Engineering_scf = c(90, 64), Environment_scf = c(19, 
    19), Finance_scf = c(455, 313), Health.Care_scf = c(105, 
    71), Human.Resources_scf = c(163, 124), Industry.Knowledge_scf = c(265, 
    174), Information.Technology_scf = c(467, 402), Legal_scf = c(21, 
    17), Maintenance..Repair..and.Installation_scf = c(194, 222
    ), Manufacturing.and.Production_scf = c(176, 174), Marketing.and.Public.Relations_scf = c(139, 
    109), Media.and.Writing_scf = c(18, 20), Personal.Care.and.Services_scf = c(31, 
    16), Public.Safety.and.National.Security_scf = c(14, 7), 
    Religion_scf = c(0, 0), Sales_scf = c(785, 463), Science.and.Research_scf = c(52, 
    24), Supply.Chain.and.Logistics_scf = c(838, 455), total_scf = c(5599, 
    3877)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), groups = structure(list(ym = c("2007-01-01", 
"2007-02-01"), NAICS2 = c(0L, 0L), occ_type = c("is_middle_manager", 
"is_middle_manager"), .rows = list(1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track but we need a your data or a sample of it to see what's going on.  Use `dput` or `dput(head())` on your data and post the structure.